# How to silent install ApacheDS on Windows

Tags: windows, installation, silent-install, apacheds

I have downloaded [ApacheDS for Windows](https://directory.apache.org/apacheds/download/download-windows.html) and I would like to silent install it to a preferred directory. The parameters `/S` and `D=` are accepted, but the service will not be installed correctly. How can I silent install ApacheDS on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following answer has been transformed into a Chocolatey Package, published to the [Chocolatey Gallery](https://chocolatey.org/) and installable using `cinst apacheds`

*I have silent installed ApacheDS by [downloading and extracting the ApacheDS zip](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/download/download-archive.html) and installed the `lib/apacheds-service-<version>.jar` as a service using [NSSM](http://nssm.cc/) ([see question and answer at StackOverflow regarding creation jar as a service on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617458/how-to-create-windows-service-from-java-jar)).*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the provided wrapper.exe in Apache DS to install the service

E.g.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ApacheDS\bin>wrapper -i ..\conf\wrapper.conf set.INSTANCE_DIRECTORY=..\instances\default set.INSTANCE=default
wrapper  | ApacheDS - default installed.
```

The full set of options are available by executing with no parameters.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ApacheDS\bin\wrapper.exe
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org

Usage:
  wrapper <command> <configuration file> [configuration properties] [...]
  wrapper <configuration file> [configuration properties] [...]
     (<command> implicitly '-c')
  wrapper <command>
     (<configuration file> implicitly 'wrapper.conf')
  wrapper
     (<command> implicitly '-c' and <configuration file> 'wrapper.conf')

where <command> can be one of:
  -c  --console  run as a Console application
  -t  --start   starT an NT service
  -a  --pause   pAuse a started NT service
  -e  --resume  rEsume a paused NT service
  -p  --stop    stoP a running NT service
  -i  --install Install as an NT service
  -r  --remove  Remove as an NT service
  -q  --query   Query the current status of the service
  -qs --querysilent Silently Query the current status of the service
  -v  --version print the wrapper's version information.
  -?  --help    print this help message

<configuration file> is the wrapper.conf to use.  Name must be absolute or relat
ive
  to the location of wrapper

[configuration properties] are configuration name-value pairs which override val
ues
  in wrapper.conf.  For example:
  wrapper.debug=true
```